# React: Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

My project keeps crashing when I attempt to insert a new recipe element.  I use the `this.state.recipes.map...` in `RecipeList` to be able to update the recipes as needed(e.g. delete,edit,etc.).  The delete functionality works, but I am unable to add a new recipe element.
If I switch the statement to `this.props.recipes.map...`, I am able to insert elements without an issue, but am unable to delete since the delete triggers a state change, and needs the state change to reflect the update instead of the props. Anyone have any tips on this issue?  Thanks!

Recipe List:

```
var RecipeList = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {recipes: []};
},
deleteRecipe: function(recipe){
    var curRecipes = this.state.recipes.slice('');
    curRecipes.splice(recipe.recipeKey,1);
    this.setState({recipes: curRecipes});
},
componentWillMount: function(){
    this.setState({recipes: this.props.recipes});
},
render: function(){

    var recipeNodes = this.state.recipes.map(function(recipe,index){
        return <Recipe onDelete={this.deleteRecipe} recipeKey={index} key={index} recipeTitle={recipe.recipeTitle} ingredients={recipe.ingredients}  instructions={recipe.instructions} />
    },this);
    return(
        <div>
            {recipeNodes}
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Recipe Container:

```
var RecipeBox = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {showForm: false,
            recipes: []
        };
},
openForm: function(){
    this.setState({showForm: true});
},
handleRecipeSubmit: function(recipe){
    var curRecipes = this.state.recipes.slice('');
    curRecipes.push({recipeTitle: recipe.recipeTitle,ingredients: recipe.ingredients, instructions: recipe.instructions});
    this.setState({recipes: curRecipes});
},
render: function(){
    return(
        <div id="recipeBox">
            <RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes} />
            <div className="recipeButtons">
                <button id="addRecipeButton" className="btn-style" onClick={this.openForm}>Add Recipe</button>
            </div>
            {this.state.showForm ? this.refs.dialogWithCallBacks.show() : null}
            <SkyLight
                dialogStyles={formDialog}
                ref="dialogWithCallBacks"
                title="Add Recipe">
                <RecipeForm onRecipeSubmit={this.handleRecipeSubmit} skylightRef={this.refs.dialogWithCallBacks} />
            </SkyLight>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Recipe Form:

```
var RecipeForm = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {hideDialog: false};
},
getFormData: function(){
    var ingredients= document.getElementsByClassName("ingredient"),
        recipeName = document.getElementsByName('recipeName')[0].value,
        instructions = document.querySelector('textarea').value,
        data = [];

    ingredients = [].slice.call(ingredients).map(function(ingredient,index){
        return {
            "quantity": ingredient.childNodes[0].value,
            "ingredient": ingredient.childNodes[1].value,
            "unit": ingredient.childNodes[2].value
        };
    });

    // Combine results into output array
    data.push(recipeName);
    data.push(ingredients);
    data.push(instructions);

    return data;
},
submitRecipe: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = this.getFormData();

    // Hide the SkyLight modal container
    this.setState({hideDialog: true});

    // Submit form
    this.props.onRecipeSubmit({recipeTitle: data[0], ingredients: data[1], instructions: data[2]});
},
render: function(){

    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.submitRecipe}>
            <section className="recipe-main">
                <h2 style={{'border-bottom': 'none'}}>Recipe Name</h2>
                <RecipeFormName />
                <h2 style={{'border-bottom': 'none'}}>Ingredients</h2>
                <RecipeFormIngredients />
            </section>
            <RecipeFormInstructions />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Recipe" />
            {this.state.hideDialog ? this.props.skylightRef.hide() : null}
        </form>
    )
}
});
```

Comment: You should never use DOM like this with react: `document.getElementsByClassName` (in your `getFormData`). Check the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Thanks. Removed `document.getElementsByClassName` and restructured how I get the form data, but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the code in componentWillMount to getInitialState.

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {recipes: this.props.recipes};
},
```

Comment: I tried this, but am still getting the same error.  Can't find where the state transition that the error mentions is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to change the RecipeList component to

`<RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes} onChange={this.handleChange}/>`

and then handle the deletion change from the `RecipeBox` instead of directly in `RecipeList`.  Have to use `this.props.map...` to display new recipes and also delete visible ones.

```
var RecipeList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {recipes: this.props.recipes};
    },
    deleteRecipe: function(recipe){
        var curRecipes = this.props.recipes.slice('');
        curRecipes.splice(recipe.recipeKey,1);
        this.props.onChange({recipes: curRecipes});
    },
    render: function(){

        var recipeNodes = this.props.recipes.map(function(recipe,index){
            return <Recipe onDelete={this.deleteRecipe} recipeKey={index} key={index} recipeName={recipe.recipeName} ingredients={recipe.ingredients}      instructions={recipe.instructions} />
        },this);

        return(
            <div>
                {recipeNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```